# How to make utility class or functional component to expose few common utility methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, utility-method

I am new to ReactJs. I have good knowledge of other OOP languages such as Java, C++, etc. That is why I am trying to find similarities between OOP and ReactJs. As we always do in Java, we make a static utility class to expose few common functionalities which are used all over the application.

How do I do it in ReactJs? My scenario is like I have few CURD methods done by Axios in Reactjs which communicates with the database. I need all CURD methods in several components. So I would like to make CurdApi.js and put all the common CURD there. Later I call them from other components. Is it possible to do in Reactjs? My possible curd API's are like:-

```
function postPhoto(selectedFile)
function postData(data)
function photo getPhoto()
function data getData()
```

Those are a hypothetical CURD that may not correct ReactJs syntax. I want to add them to a utility class or functional component to reuse all over the ReactJs App. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely add them to a js file and have them imported to the component you want.
You can have your methods as static like this.

```
export default class MyUtility {
    static postPhoto(selectedFile) {
        return true;
    }

    static postData(data) {
        return true;
    }

    static getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    static getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

And use them in the component:

```
import MyUtility from '../../Common/myUtility';

let result = MyUtility.postPhoto(mySelectedFile);
```